# Using NSString stringWithFormat: with a string from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I'm getting an NSString from a dictionary that needs to have a variable integer, something like:

```
"You have %i objects."
```

How do I put the calculated integer value into the string? I would like to do something like

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dictionary objectForKey:@"string"]
```

But I don't know how to pass in an argument to stringWithFormat when the %i is tucked away in the dictionary.

Note: I can work around this by using stringByReplaceOccurenceOfString, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do it in the above way.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you show me some examples of the dictionary data and the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a comma separated list of arguments to methods like stringWithFormat:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    [dictionary objectForKey:@"string"] , 7 , 8 , 9];
```

Only the 7 would be used in your sample format string.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was doing, and this turned out to be one of those times where the problem was somewhere else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it using this

```
  NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:[dictionary objectForKey:@"string"],YOURINTNUMBER];
```

It will work